# Cannot Publish Project to Azure, Publish Option Not Available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, xamarin

i'm just starting to play around with azure, I'm going through the tutorial for XamarinIOS. When I get to the step to publish, I cant even get the publish option available when I right click its just not there. Im using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Heres the link to the tutorial.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started/

I get all the way to Publish your mobile service step.

I do get a warning when I build, look below.

Warning 1   Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have downloaded the PublishSettings file first before you can deploy.  This is shown in Step 2 of the "Publish your mobile service" on the page you linked to.  If you don't have this file the publishing framework won't know where to deploy your mobile services code to.